# How to get frequency of words in text depends of they part of speech?

Tags: python, nltk

I can easy get most common words by:

```
stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))    
tagged_words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(tagged_words)

# Remove single-character tokens (mostly punctuation)
tagged_words = [tagged_word for tagged_word in tagged_words if len(tagged_word[0]) > 1]

# Remove numbers
tagged_words = [tagged_word for tagged_word in tagged_words if not tagged_word[0].isnumeric()]

# Remove stopwords
if remove_stopwords:
    tagged_words = [tagged_word for tagged_word in tagged_words if tagged_word[0] not in stopwords]

# Dark magic
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
words = []
for tagged_word in tagged_words:
    pos = wordnet_pos_code(tagged_word[1])
    # Ignoring all words, except nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs
    if pos is not None:
        words.append({'word':lemmatizer.lemmatize(tagged_word[0], pos=pos), 'pos':tagged_word[1]})

# Calculate frequency distribution
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

# Return top % words_count % words
res = []
for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(words_count):
    word_dict = {}
    word_dict['word'] = word
    word_dict['count'] = frequency
    res.append(word_dict)
return res
```

But i got some words like 'Brown' as person name and 'brown' as color and they are not same. Okay, i can check them by capital letter. But if i get something like:

> Brown is not just a color. Brown is part of lifestyle. And Mr Brown should agree with me.

So, nltk does part-of-speech analysis pretty good. But how can i get most common words depends on part-of-speech?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one better solution: collect words and pos as array of tuples and get their frequency by FreqDist.

```
tagged_words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(tagged_words)
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
words = []
for tagged_word in tagged_words:
    pos = wordnet_pos_code(tagged_word[1])

    if pos is not None:
        words.append((lemmatizer.lemmatize(tagged_word[0], pos=pos), tagged_word[1]))

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
```

So, now i can put them sorted into array.

```
res = []
for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(words_count):
    word_dict = {}
    word_dict['word'] = word
    word_dict['count'] = frequency
    res.append(word_dict)
return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `defaultdict` with `words` as key and a `Counter` object as value. And for the inner `Counter`, the key is the POS and the value is the count of the POS given the word.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> corpus_counts = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for word, tag in brown.tagged_words():
...     if word in corpus_counts:
...             corpus_counts[word][tag] +=1
...     else:
...             corpus_counts[word] = Counter({tag:1})
... 
>>> 
>>> corpus_counts['run']
Counter({u'VB': 122, u'NN': 52, u'VBN': 31, u'VBD': 1})
>>> corpus_counts['run']['VB']
122
```